# How to give auto custom header on codeblocks?

Tags: codeblocks

Every time when I open a new file in codeblocks, it is an empty file. But I want my files to have this headers (shown on the image file) which will be there, whenever i will create a new cpp file. But i didn't find any option to create this. Googled but didn't find where is this option in codeblocks

[image]
this is the headers

Comment: Learn [Why you should not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1362568)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use my own Made tools to get rid of these problem. You can add that tools in codeblocks then you can easily open new file with custom header/skeleton. You can check that out here. [Github link.](https://github.com/goldenbijoy/SkeletonCodeBlocks). If you have any issue with it.. feel free to ask. Thanks.